# Global variable and extern

Tags: c++, extern

I have this three files
header.h

```
extern int global_var;
```

header.cpp

```
#include "header.h"
int global_var=50;
```

main.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include "header.h"
using namespace std;
global_var+=100;

int main(){
cout<<global_var;

}
```

when I run the prog error occurred :
global_var  does not name a type

I know when I put global var inside main function work
but I want to know why this problem occurred

Comment: `global_var+=100;` you can't write assignment expressions outside of a function - move this code into `main`.